# POST запрос в контролер ASP.NET. Обрезает строку передаваемого параметра после пробела

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть метод:

```
public PartialViewResult add(string FirstName, string SecondName, string Patronymic, string Position, string CurrentDivisionList)
        {
            Structure.Workers.Add(new Worker
            {
                FirstName = FirstName,
                SecondName = SecondName,
                Patronymic = Patronymic,
                Position = Position,
                DivisionName = CurrentDivisionList,
            });
            Structure.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("UpdateTable", Structure.Workers);
        }
```

Проблема: обрезает строку после пробела.
Например, если входящий параметр `привет мир` то запишет только `привет`.

Вот форма

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("add", "Home",new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "record-table", HttpMethod = "Post"
    }, new { @class = "Addform"}))
{
    @Html.Label("FirstName", "Фамилия")
    @Html.TextBox("FirstName", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите Фамилию", @required = "" })
    @Html.Label("SecondName", "Имя")
    @Html.TextBox("SecondName", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите Имя", @required = "" })
    @Html.Label("Patronymic", "Отчество")
    @Html.TextBox("Patronymic", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите Отчество", @required = "" })
    @Html.Label("Position", "Должность")
    @Html.TextBox("Position", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Введите Должность", @required = ""})
    @Html.Label("DivisionType", "Подразделение")
    @Html.DropDownList("DivisionType", DivisionType, "--Выберите тип--", new { @class = "form-control main-add-form" })
    @Html.Label("CurrentDivisionList", "Подразделения выбраного типа")
    @Html.DropDownList("CurrentDivisionList", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Выберите тип--", new { @class = "form-control main-add-form-select" })
<button class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit">Добавить</button>
}
```

Думаю, в запрос попадет только часть до пробела. Как исправить, подскажите?

HTML разметка

```
    <form action="/Home/add" class="Addform" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#record-table" id="form0" method="post">
<label for="FirstName">Фамилия</label>
<input class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Введите Фамилию" required="" type="text" value="" />
<label for="SecondName">Имя</label>
<input class="form-control" id="SecondName" name="SecondName" placeholder="Введите Имя" required="" type="text" value="" />
<label for="Patronymic">Отчество</label>
<input class="form-control" id="Patronymic" name="Patronymic" placeholder="Введите Отчество" required="" type="text" value="" />
<label for="Position">Должность</label>
<input class="form-control" id="Position" name="Position" placeholder="Введите Должность" required="" type="text" value="" />
<label for="DivisionType">Подразделение</label>
<select class="form-control main-add-form" id="DivisionType" name="DivisionType">
    <option value="">--Выберите тип--</option>
    <option value="Управление">Управление</option>
    <option value="Отдел">Отдел</option>
    <option value="Группа">Группа</option>
    </select>
<label for="CurrentDivisionList">Подразделения выбранного типа</label>
<select class="form-control main-add-form-select" id="CurrentDivisionList" name="CurrentDivisionList">
<option value="">--Выберите тип--</option>
    </select>    
<button class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Пробовал на английском? Проверь через дебагер, в контроллер нормальные данные поступают? Если ошибка на форме, попробуй заменить `TextBox` на `TextBoxFor`, так же удалить параметр `@required = ""`

Comment: смотрел в гул хроме что отправлят так и есть обрезает все после пробела. а зачем required удаалять я хочу  что ыб пусто поле могло отправитсч

Comment: без разницы на каком языке

Comment: у меня проблема с выпадающим списком из него режет.

Comment: Проблема с `DivisionType`, верно? Добавьте в вопрос HTML-код формы, который генерирует *Razor* для этого представления.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Проблема решена (не  так разметку генерировал), и запрос вообще ни при чем. Вот так верно:

```
$(".form-control.modal-edit-form-select").append('<option value="' + val.DivisionName + '">' + val.DivisionName + '</option>');
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то была? Вы не использовали кавычки при задании значения атрибуту `value`?

Comment: да не так кавычки написал)